# python mocking configobj's return value

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, patch

I have a method that I would like to create a unittest for. ConfigObj is just a library for parsing config files. The method is very simple:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj


def read_name():
    conf = ConfigObj('/data/myfile')
    return conf['name']
```

conf['name'] returns a string value of the 'name' setting in the file.
I am trying to write a unit test to mock this return behavior, but I am running into a "KeyError" on conf['name']. It doesn't look like the conf instance was mocked at all.

My test so far:

```
@mock.patch('configobj.ConfigObj')
def test_read_name(self, mock_configobj):
    config = mock_configobj.return_value
    config.__getitem__.side_effect = 'tom'
    self.assertEqual(read_name(), 'tom')
```

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out it was very simple

```
@patch('configobj.ConfigObj.__getitem__', return_value='tom')
    def test_get_name(self, mock_configobj)
    self.assertEqual(read_name(), 'tom')
```